# Madir vs Mudar vs Noder

Tags: talmud-gemara, words, nedarim-shevuot

What are the roles of מדיר / מודר / נודר when it comes to נדרים?

Originally I thought the Madir is the one who makes the Neder that makes an item forbidden,
The Mudar is the subject to whom the item is forbidden (which sometimes can be the Madir himself),
And Noder is just an alternate term for Madir.

Yet sometimes it seems like Madir and Mudar are explained in the opposite fashion,
and I've also seen Noder and Madir on opposite sides *(For example, [Ran Nedarim 42a](https://www.sefaria.org/Nedarim.42a.4?lang=bi&with=Ran)  ד''ה לימא starting 2nd wide line where quotes 46a)*

Are there clear definitions to the roles each one of these people play?